# Camera freezes after screen lock

Tags: java, android, android-camera

I am developing a barcode scanner using zbar for Android.
Everything is working fine. But, when my application goes to sleep or my phone locks, the camera preview get froze and I can't restart it in on resume.

fragment.java

```
package com.alsafeer.xpressions.fragment;

import android.graphics.Typeface;
import android.hardware.Camera;
import android.os.AsyncTask;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.os.Handler;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentManager;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentTransaction;
import android.view.KeyEvent;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.view.WindowManager;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.RelativeLayout;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;

import com.alsafeer.xpressions.AnalyticsSampleApp;
import com.alsafeer.xpressions.CameraPreview;
import com.alsafeer.xpressions.JsonParser;
import com.alsafeer.xpressions.R;
import com.google.android.gms.analytics.GoogleAnalytics;
import com.google.android.gms.analytics.HitBuilders;
import com.google.android.gms.analytics.Tracker;

import net.sourceforge.zbar.Config;
import net.sourceforge.zbar.Image;
import net.sourceforge.zbar.ImageScanner;
import net.sourceforge.zbar.Symbol;
import net.sourceforge.zbar.SymbolSet;

import org.json.JSONArray;
import org.json.JSONException;
import org.json.JSONObject;


public class rewards extends Fragment {
private Camera mCamera;
private CameraPreview mPreview;
private Handler autoFocusHandler;
private String Name;
private String Email;
private View view;
private String Mob;
private String Points;
private String result;
private RelativeLayout preview;

TextView scanText;
Button scanButton;

ImageScanner scanner;

private boolean barcodeScanned = false;
private boolean previewing = true;

static {
    System.loadLibrary("iconv");
}


@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    setHasOptionsMenu(true);
    view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.activity_rewards,
            container, false);
    view.setFocusableInTouchMode(true);
    view.requestFocus();
    Tracker t = ((AnalyticsSampleApp) getActivity().getApplication()).getTracker(
            AnalyticsSampleApp.TrackerName.APP_TRACKER);
    GoogleAnalytics.getInstance(getActivity()).setLocalDispatchPeriod(1);
    t.setScreenName("Rewards Barcode Reader");
    t.send(new HitBuilders.AppViewBuilder().build());
    Typeface font = Typeface.createFromAsset(getActivity().getAssets(), "fonts/font.ttf");
    Button next= (Button) view.findViewById(R.id.next);
    next.setTypeface(font);
    scanText = (EditText)view.findViewById(R.id.editText6);
    scanText.setTypeface(font);
    mCamera = getCameraInstance();
    getActivity().getWindow().setSoftInputMode(WindowManager.LayoutParams.SOFT_INPUT_STATE_VISIBLE|
            WindowManager.LayoutParams.SOFT_INPUT_ADJUST_RESIZE);
    next.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            if(!scanText.getText().toString().equals(""))
            {
                new AsyncTaskParseJson().execute();
            }
            else
            {
                Toast.makeText(getActivity(),"Please enter the number or scan the barcode...", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }
        }
    });
        scanText.setOnKeyListener(new View.OnKeyListener() {
            @Override
            public boolean onKey(View v, int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {
                if (event.getAction() == KeyEvent.ACTION_DOWN) {
                    if ((keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_BACK)) {
                        releaseCamera();
                        getFragmentManager().beginTransaction().replace(R.id.content_frame, new FirstFragment(), "first").commit();
                        return true;
                    }

                }
                return false;
            }
        });
    view.setOnKeyListener(new View.OnKeyListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onKey(View v, int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {
            if (event.getAction() == KeyEvent.ACTION_DOWN) {
                if ((keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_BACK)) {
                    releaseCamera();
                    getFragmentManager().beginTransaction().replace(R.id.content_frame, new FirstFragment(), "first").commit();
                    return true;
                }
            }
            return true;
        }
    });

    autoFocusHandler = new Handler();


    /* Instance barcode scanner */
    scanner = new ImageScanner();
    scanner.setConfig(0, Config.X_DENSITY, 3);
    scanner.setConfig(0, Config.Y_DENSITY, 3);

    mPreview = new CameraPreview(getActivity(), mCamera, previewCb, autoFocusCB);
    preview = (RelativeLayout) view.findViewById(R.id.cameraPreview);
    preview.addView(mPreview);
    scanButton = (Button)view.findViewById(R.id.button6);
    scanButton.setTypeface(font);
    scanButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View v) {
            if (barcodeScanned) {
                barcodeScanned = false;
                mCamera.setPreviewCallback(previewCb);
                mCamera.startPreview();
                previewing = true;
                mCamera.autoFocus(autoFocusCB);
            }
        }
    });
    return view;
}

@Override
public void onResume() {
    super.onResume();
    if(mCamera==null) {
        mCamera=getCameraInstance();
        mPreview = new CameraPreview(getActivity(), mCamera, previewCb, autoFocusCB);
        preview = (RelativeLayout) view.findViewById(R.id.cameraPreview);
        preview.addView(mPreview);
        mCamera.setPreviewCallback(previewCb);
        mCamera.startPreview();
        previewing = true;
        mCamera.autoFocus(autoFocusCB);
    }

}

@Override
public void onPause() {
    super.onPause();

}

@Override
public void onStop() {
    super.onStop();
    releaseCamera();
}

/** A safe way to get an instance of the Camera object. */
public static Camera getCameraInstance(){
    Camera c = null;
    try {
        c = Camera.open();
    } catch (Exception e){
    }
    return c;
}

public void releaseCamera() {
    if (mCamera != null) {
        previewing = false;
        mCamera.setPreviewCallback(null);
        mCamera.release();
        mCamera = null;
    }
}

private Runnable doAutoFocus = new Runnable() {
    public void run() {
        if (previewing)
            mCamera.autoFocus(autoFocusCB);
    }
};

Camera.PreviewCallback previewCb = new Camera.PreviewCallback() {
    public void onPreviewFrame(byte[] data, Camera camera) {
        Camera.Parameters parameters = camera.getParameters();
        Camera.Size size = parameters.getPreviewSize();

        Image barcode = new Image(size.width, size.height, "Y800");
        barcode.setData(data);

        int result = scanner.scanImage(barcode);

        if (result != 0) {
            previewing = false;
            mCamera.setPreviewCallback(null);
            mCamera.stopPreview();

            SymbolSet syms = scanner.getResults();
            for (Symbol sym : syms) {
                scanText.setText(sym.getData());
                barcodeScanned = true;
            }
        }
    }
};

// Mimic continuous auto-focusing
Camera.AutoFocusCallback autoFocusCB = new Camera.AutoFocusCallback() {
    public void onAutoFocus(boolean success, Camera camera) {
        autoFocusHandler.postDelayed(doAutoFocus, 1000);
    }
};
public class AsyncTaskParseJson extends AsyncTask<String, String, String> {
    JSONArray dataJsonArr = null;

    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {}

    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(String... arg0) {

        try {

            // instantiate our json parser
            JsonParser jParser = new JsonParser();

            // get json string from url
            JSONObject json = jParser.getJSONFromUrl("http://www.safeerplus.ae/ncno="+scanText.getText().toString());

            // get the array of users
            dataJsonArr = json.getJSONArray("msg");

            // loop through all users

            JSONObject c = dataJsonArr.getJSONObject(0);

            // Storing each json item in variable
            Name = c.getString("name");
            Mob = c.getString("mob");
            Email = c.getString("email");
            Points = c.getString("points");
            if(Name.equals("")||Mob.equals("")||Email.equals("")||Points.equals(""))
            {

            }
            else {
                Bundle args = new Bundle();
                args.putString("code", scanText.getText().toString());
                args.putString("name1", Name);
                args.putString("mob1", Mob);
                args.putString("email1", Email);
                args.putString("points1", Points);
                releaseCamera();
                Fragment fr=new reward_details();
                FragmentManager fm = getFragmentManager();
                FragmentTransaction ft = fm.beginTransaction();
                fr.setArguments(args);
                ft.replace(R.id.content_frame, fr);
                ft.commit();
            }



        } catch (JSONException e) {
            getActivity().runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                public void run() {

                    Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "Please use a valid card!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                }
            });

        }
      return null;
    }


    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(String strFromDoInBg) {}
}
}
```

camerapreview.java

```
package com.alsafeer.xpressions;

import android.content.Context;
import android.hardware.Camera;
import android.hardware.Camera.AutoFocusCallback;
import android.hardware.Camera.PreviewCallback;
import android.util.DisplayMetrics;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.SurfaceHolder;
import android.view.SurfaceView;


public class CameraPreview extends SurfaceView implements SurfaceHolder.Callback {
private SurfaceHolder mHolder;
private Camera mCamera;
private PreviewCallback previewCallback;
private AutoFocusCallback autoFocusCallback;

public CameraPreview(Context context, Camera camera,
                     PreviewCallback previewCb,
                     AutoFocusCallback autoFocusCb) {
    super(context);
    mCamera = camera;
    previewCallback = previewCb;
    autoFocusCallback = autoFocusCb;

    /* 
     * Set camera to continuous focus if supported, otherwise use
     * software auto-focus. Only works for API level >=9.
     */
    /*
    Camera.Parameters parameters = camera.getParameters();
    for (String f : parameters.getSupportedFocusModes()) {
        if (f == Parameters.FOCUS_MODE_CONTINUOUS_PICTURE) {
            mCamera.setFocusMode(Parameters.FOCUS_MODE_CONTINUOUS_PICTURE);
            autoFocusCallback = null;
            break;
        }
    }
    */

    // Install a SurfaceHolder.Callback so we get notified when the
    // underlying surface is created and destroyed.
    mHolder = getHolder();
    mHolder.addCallback(this);

    // deprecated setting, but required on Android versions prior to 3.0
    mHolder.setType(SurfaceHolder.SURFACE_TYPE_PUSH_BUFFERS);
}

public void surfaceCreated(SurfaceHolder holder) {
    // The Surface has been created, now tell the camera where to draw the preview.
    try {
        // open the camera
        mCamera = Camera.open();
    } catch (RuntimeException e) {
        // check for exceptions
        System.err.println(e);
        return;
    }
    Camera.Parameters param;
    param = mCamera.getParameters();

    // modify parameter
    param.setPreviewSize(200, 300);
    mCamera.setParameters(param);
    try {
        // The Surface has been created, now tell the camera where to draw
        // the preview.
        mCamera.setPreviewDisplay(holder);
        mCamera.startPreview();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        // check for exceptions
        System.err.println(e);
        return;
    }
}
@Override
protected void onMeasure(int widthMeasureSpec, int heightMeasureSpec) {
    super.onMeasure(widthMeasureSpec, heightMeasureSpec);
    setMeasuredDimension(getMeasuredWidth(), getMeasuredWidth()); //Snap to width
}

public void surfaceDestroyed(SurfaceHolder holder) {

}

public void surfaceChanged(SurfaceHolder holder, int format, int width, int height) {
    Camera.Parameters parameters = mCamera.getParameters();
    final DisplayMetrics dm = this.getResources().getDisplayMetrics();
    //getBestPreviewSize returns the best preview size, don't worry
    //but some devices do not return one for all camera matching the aspect ratio

    /*
     * If your preview can change or rotate, take care of those events here.
     * Make sure to stop the preview before resizing or reformatting it.
     */
    if (mHolder.getSurface() == null){
      // preview surface does not exist
      return;
    }

    // stop preview before making changes
    try {
        mCamera.stopPreview();
    } catch (Exception e){
      // ignore: tried to stop a non-existent preview
    }

    try {
        // Hard code camera surface rotation 90 degs to match Activity view in portrait
        mCamera.setDisplayOrientation(90);

        mCamera.setPreviewDisplay(mHolder);
        mCamera.setPreviewCallback(previewCallback);
        mCamera.startPreview();
        mCamera.autoFocus(autoFocusCallback);
    } catch (Exception e){
        Log.d("DBG", "Error starting camera preview: " + e.getMessage());
    }
}
}
```

Layout.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:padding="16dp"
android:background="#e7e7e9">

<RelativeLayout
    android:id="@+id/cameraPreview"
    android:layout_width="300dp"
    android:layout_height="300dp"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:gravity="clip_horizontal"
    android:layout_below="@+id/editText6"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true">

</RelativeLayout>

<Button
    android:id="@+id/next"
    android:text="View points"
    android:layout_width="120dp"
    android:layout_height="30sp"
    android:layout_gravity="center"
    android:background="@drawable/loginbutton"
    android:textSize="12sp"
    android:layout_alignTop="@+id/button6"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:layout_alignParentEnd="true" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/button6"
    android:text="Rescan"
    android:layout_width="120dp"
    android:layout_height="30sp"
    android:layout_gravity="center"
    android:background="@drawable/loginbutton"
    android:textSize="12sp"
    android:layout_below="@+id/cameraPreview"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
    android:layout_marginTop="30dp" />

<EditText
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:inputType="number"
    android:ems="10"
    android:id="@+id/editText6"
    android:background="#d1d2d4"
    android:textSize="15sp"
    android:padding="5dp"
    android:textColor="#000000"
    android:hint="Enter or Scan the Barcode"
    android:textColorHint="#4a4f5a"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/cameraPreview"
    android:layout_alignStart="@+id/cameraPreview"
    android:layout_alignRight="@+id/cameraPreview"
    android:layout_alignEnd="@+id/cameraPreview" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

logcat

```
04-20 10:40:20.356    7099-7099/com.alsafeer.xpressions D/Camera-JNI﹕ setHasPreviewCallback: installed:1, manualBuffer:0
04-20 10:40:20.359    7099-7099/com.alsafeer.xpressions I/CameraFramework﹕ Camera framework getParameters =afeng-max-focus-step=0;afeng-min-focus-step=0;antibanding=auto;antibanding-values=off,50hz,60hz,auto;auto-exposure-lock-supported=true;auto-whitebalance-lock-supported=true;brightness=middle;brightness-values=low,middle,high;brightness_value=39;burst-num=1;cap-mode=normal;cap-mode-values=normal,face_beauty,continuousshot,smileshot,bestshot,evbracketshot,autorama,mav,asd;capfname=/sdcard/DCIM/cap00;contrast=middle;contrast-values=low,middle,high;edge=middle;edge-values=low,middle,high;effect=none;effect-values=none,mono,negative,sepia,aqua,whiteboard,blackboard;eng-flash-duty-max=1;eng-flash-duty-min=0;eng-flash-duty-value=-1;exposure-compensation=0;exposure-compensation-step=1.0;fb-sharp=0;fb-sharp-max=4;fb-sharp-min=-4;fb-skin-color=0;fb-skin-color-max=4;fb-skin-color-min=-4;fb-smooth-level=0;fb-smooth-level-max=4;fb-smooth-level-min=-4;focal-length=3.5;focus-distances=0.95,1.9,Infinity;focus-mode=infinity;focus-mode-values=infinity;horizontal-view-angle=54;hue=middle;hue-values=low,middle,high;iso-speed=auto;iso-speed-values=auto,100,200,400,800,1600;jpeg-quality=100;jpeg-thumbnail-height=128;jpeg-thumbnail-quality=100;jpeg-thumbnail-size-values=0x0,160x128,320x240;jpeg-thumbnail-width=160;max-exposure-compensation=3;max-num-detected-faces-hw=15;max-num-detected-faces-sw=0;max-num-focus-areas=0;max-num-metering-areas=9;max-zoom=10;min-exposure-compensation=-3;mtk-cam-mode=0;picture-format=jpeg;picture-format-values=jpeg;picture-size=2560x1920;picture-size-values=320x240,640x480,1024x768,1280x720,1280x768,1280x960,1600x1200,2048x1536,2560x1440,2560x1920,2880x1728;preferred-preview-size-for-video=1280x720;preview-format=yuv420sp;preview-format-values=yuv420sp,yuv420p,yuv420i-yyuvyy-3plane;preview-fps-range=5000,60000;preview-fps-range-values=(5000,60000);preview-frame-rate=30;preview-frame-rate-values=15,24,30;preview-size=640x480;preview-size-values=176x144,320x240,352x288,480x320,480x368,640x480,720x480,800x480,800x600,864x480,960x540,1280x720;rotation=0;saturation=middle;saturation-values=low,middle,high;scene-mode=auto;scene-mode-values=auto,portrait,landscape,night,night-portrait,theatre,beach,snow,sunset,steadyphoto,fireworks,sports,party,candlelight,hdr;sensor-type=254;smooth-zoom-supported=true;vertical-view-angle=49;video-frame-format=yuv420p;video-size=640x480;video-size-values=176x144,480x320,640x480,864x480,1280x720,1920x1080;video-snapshot-supported=false;video-stabilization=false;video-stabilization-supported=true;whitebalance=auto;whitebalance-values=auto,incandescent,fluorescent,warm-fluorescent,daylight,cloudy-daylight,twilight,shade;zoom=0;zoom-ratios=100,114,132,151,174,200,229,263,303,348,400;zoom-supported=true;zsd-mode=off;zsd-mode-values=off,on
04-20 10:40:20.390    7099-7112/com.alsafeer.xpressions D/Camera-JNI﹕ Allocating callback buffer
04-20 10:40:20.418    7099-7099/com.alsafeer.xpressions I/CameraFramework﹕ handleMessage: 16
04-20 10:40:20.418    7099-7099/com.alsafeer.xpressions D/Camera-JNI﹕ setHasPreviewCallback: installed:1, manualBuffer:0
04-20 10:40:20.420    7099-7099/com.alsafeer.xpressions I/CameraFramework﹕ Camera framework getParameters =afeng-max-focus-step=0;afeng-min-focus-step=0;antibanding=auto;antibanding-values=off,50hz,60hz,auto;auto-exposure-lock-supported=true;auto-whitebalance-lock-supported=true;brightness=middle;brightness-values=low,middle,high;brightness_value=39;burst-num=1;cap-mode=normal;cap-mode-values=normal,face_beauty,continuousshot,smileshot,bestshot,evbracketshot,autorama,mav,asd;capfname=/sdcard/DCIM/cap00;contrast=middle;contrast-values=low,middle,high;edge=middle;edge-values=low,middle,high;effect=none;effect-values=none,mono,negative,sepia,aqua,whiteboard,blackboard;eng-flash-duty-max=1;eng-flash-duty-min=0;eng-flash-duty-value=-1;exposure-compensation=0;exposure-compensation-step=1.0;fb-sharp=0;fb-sharp-max=4;fb-sharp-min=-4;fb-skin-color=0;fb-skin-color-max=4;fb-skin-color-min=-4;fb-smooth-level=0;fb-smooth-level-max=4;fb-smooth-level-min=-4;focal-length=3.5;focus-distances=0.95,1.9,Infinity;focus-mode=infinity;focus-mode-values=infinity;horizontal-view-angle=54;hue=middle;hue-values=low,middle,high;iso-speed=auto;iso-speed-values=auto,100,200,400,800,1600;jpeg-quality=100;jpeg-thumbnail-height=128;jpeg-thumbnail-quality=100;jpeg-thumbnail-size-values=0x0,160x128,320x240;jpeg-thumbnail-width=160;max-exposure-compensation=3;max-num-detected-faces-hw=15;max-num-detected-faces-sw=0;max-num-focus-areas=0;max-num-metering-areas=9;max-zoom=10;min-exposure-compensation=-3;mtk-cam-mode=0;picture-format=jpeg;picture-format-values=jpeg;picture-size=2560x1920;picture-size-values=320x240,640x480,1024x768,1280x720,1280x768,1280x960,1600x1200,2048x1536,2560x1440,2560x1920,2880x1728;preferred-preview-size-for-video=1280x720;preview-format=yuv420sp;preview-format-values=yuv420sp,yuv420p,yuv420i-yyuvyy-3plane;preview-fps-range=5000,60000;preview-fps-range-values=(5000,60000);preview-frame-rate=30;preview-frame-rate-values=15,24,30;preview-size=640x480;preview-size-values=176x144,320x240,352x288,480x320,480x368,640x480,720x480,800x480,800x600,864x480,960x540,1280x720;rotation=0;saturation=middle;saturation-values=low,middle,high;scene-mode=auto;scene-mode-values=auto,portrait,landscape,night,night-portrait,theatre,beach,snow,sunset,steadyphoto,fireworks,sports,party,candlelight,hdr;sensor-type=254;smooth-zoom-supported=true;vertical-view-angle=49;video-frame-format=yuv420p;video-size=640x480;video-size-values=176x144,480x320,640x480,864x480,1280x720,1920x1080;video-snapshot-supported=false;video-stabilization=false;video-stabilization-supported=true;whitebalance=auto;whitebalance-values=auto,incandescent,fluorescent,warm-fluorescent,daylight,cloudy-daylight,twilight,shade;zoom=0;zoom-ratios=100,114,132,151,174,200,229,263,303,348,400;zoom-supported=true;zsd-mode=off;zsd-mode-values=off,on
04-20 10:40:20.457    7099-7099/com.alsafeer.xpressions D/Camera-JNI﹕ setHasPreviewCallback: installed:0, manualBuffer:0
04-20 10:40:20.458    7099-7112/com.alsafeer.xpressions W/Camera-JNI﹕ callback on dead camera object
04-20 10:40:20.458    7099-7099/com.alsafeer.xpressions D/Camera-JNI﹕ (tid:7099)[native_release] + context=0x66e3fc70 camera=0x63f70e30
04-20 10:40:20.458    7099-7099/com.alsafeer.xpressions D/Camera-JNI﹕ [native_release] context->getStrongCount(2) camera->getStrongCount(2)
04-20 10:40:21.023    7099-7099/com.alsafeer.xpressions D/Camera-JNI﹕ (tid:7099)[native_release] - context=0x66e3fc70 camera=0x0
04-20 10:40:21.023    7099-7099/com.alsafeer.xpressions D/Camera-JNI﹕ (tid:7099)[release camera] - X context=0x66e3fc70
04-20 10:40:21.024    7099-7111/com.alsafeer.xpressions D/IPCThreadState﹕ [DN #5] BR_CLEAR_DEATH_NOTIFICATION_DONE cookie 0x66e3fba8
04-20 10:40:21.027    7099-7151/com.alsafeer.xpressions D/Camera-JNI﹕ (tid:7151)[~MtkJNICameraContext] this:0x66e3fc70
04-20 10:40:21.066    7099-7099/com.alsafeer.xpressions I/Choreographer﹕ Skipped 41 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
04-20 10:40:21.089    7099-7099/com.alsafeer.xpressions D/GraphicBuffer﹕ create handle(0x623e35c0) (w:480, h:790, f:1)
04-20 10:40:21.121    7099-7099/com.alsafeer.xpressions I/SurfaceTextureClient﹕ [STC::queueBuffer] (this:0x63159d68) fps:0.09, dur:10931.96, max:10931.96, min:10931.96
04-20 10:40:21.121    7099-7099/com.alsafeer.xpressions I/SurfaceTextureClient﹕ [STC::queueBuffer] this:0x63159d68, api:1, last queue time elapsed:10931.96
04-20 10:40:21.130    7099-7099/com.alsafeer.xpressions D/OpenGLRenderer﹕ Flushing caches (mode 0)
```

Comment: What does logcat say?

Comment: 04-20 10:19:14.283  18402-18402/com.alsafeer.xpressions D/Camera-JNI﹕ (tid:18402)[release camera] - X context=0x630a3120
04-20 10:19:14.286  18402-18402/com.alsafeer.xpressions W/InputMethodManager﹕ startInputInner : InputBindResult == null
04-20 10:19:14.286  18402-18402/com.alsafeer.xpressions I/CameraFramework﹕ handleMessage: 16
04-20 10:19:14.287  18402-18402/com.alsafeer.xpressions I/Choreographer﹕ Skipped 38 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.

Comment: updated with logcat..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It seems that at every time the app resumes (onResume) you are recreating your CameraPreview view and adding it to your layout. Does this problem also happens when you are in your app, switch to another and then come back? If it also freezes in this situation, I would suspect you would need to remove the older CameraPreview view instance from the layout before adding the new one.

Comment: But, the fact is, u can see releasecamera() i hav called in onStop() method... if i remove it, the preview wont freeze on screelock, but when i try to open the camera again, it force close... it says Camera.Parameters parameters = mCamera.getParameters(); return null...

Comment: Yeah, but I actually meant to remove the view from the layout before adding a new one in `onResume()` like  this:

`preview = (RelativeLayout) view.findViewById(R.id.cameraPreview);
 preview.removeView(mPreview);
 mPreview = new CameraPreview(getActivity(), mCamera, previewCb, autoFocusCB);
 preview.addView(mPreview);`

Comment: You saved my day too, 4+ years later. :-)